# Asp Identity Two Factor Authentication not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2, two-factor-authentication

So I am trying to get Two Factor Authentication to work in my MVC 5 app using ASP Identity but whenever `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()` is called it always returns Success regardless if Two Factor Authentication is enabled or not.
[image: user props]

As you can see the user has a confirmed email and the TwoFactorEnabled Prop is set to true.
Here's my IdentityConfig:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using AEMS.Models;
using Domain;
using Twilio.Mvc;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;
using Twilio.Types;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace AEMS
{


    public class EmailService : IIdentityMessageService
    {

        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            // Plug in your email service here to send an email.

            String userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailFrom"];
            String password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailPassword"];
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(message.Destination));
            msg.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailFrom"]);
            msg.Subject = message.Subject;
            msg.Body = message.Body;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailHost"];
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailFrom"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailPassword"]);
            client.Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailPort"]);
            client.EnableSsl = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailEnableSSL"]);
            client.Send(msg);
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }

    public class SmsService : IIdentityMessageService
    {
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
        {
            // Plug in your SMS service here to send a text message.
            //Set our AccountSid and AuthToken
            string AccountSid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMSAccountSid"];
            string AuthToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMSAuthToken"];

            //Instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
            TwilioClient.Init(AccountSid, AuthToken);
            var sendMessage = MessageResource.CreateAsync(
                message.Destination,
                from: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMSAccountFrom"],
                body: message.Body);

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }

    // Configure the application user manager used in this application. UserManager is defined in ASP.NET Identity and is used by the application.
    public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
            : base(store)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
        {
            var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
            // Configure validation logic for usernames
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
            {
                AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
                RequireUniqueEmail = true,
            };

            // Configure validation logic for passwords
            manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
            {
                RequiredLength = 6,
                RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
                RequireDigit = true,
                RequireLowercase = true,
                RequireUppercase = true,
            };

            //Configure user lockout defaults
            manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault =
                Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserLockoutEnabledByDefault"].ToString());
            manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan =
                TimeSpan.FromHours(Double.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan"].ToString()));
            manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout =
                Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout"].ToString());
            //manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
            //manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            //manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

            // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
            // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("PhoneCode", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("EmailCode", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
            {
                Subject = "Security Code",
                BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
            });
            manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
            manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
            var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
            if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
            {
                manager.UserTokenProvider = 
                    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
            }
            return manager;
        }
    }

    // Configure the application sign-in manager which is used in this application.
    public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
    {
        public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
            : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
        {
        }

        public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
        }

        public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing

Comment: Could you copy and paste that IdentifyConfig code into the question body itself, as text, instead of posting a screenshot?

Comment: @Christine I swapped out the screenshot with the code

Comment: I figured it out. The IdentifyConfig wasn't the problem. The issue was with the application using Dependency Injection to inject the SignInManager into the controller and the SignInManager not coming from the current HttpContext .